# Strip all Swift symbol in iOS app

Tags: swift, symbols, strip

I'm having trouble stripping my Swift application for iOS.
I disable bitcode in Xcode so I have a "real" binary at the end and I enabled stripping in Xcode like so:

[image]

It works fine for function/method names but I still have my class/struct/enums symbol names in the final binary (I have some "fake" class and structs called FindMe to show you):

[image: Hopper showing my symbols name]

Is that a normal behaviour? Can I get rid of them? Or is Swift working dynamically like Obj-C with symbol resolution (like obj_send).

Comment: did you find a solution for this? Found this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/CppRuntimeEnv/Articles/SymbolVisibility.html), however i cant find the equivalent in swift. I also tried GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN with no results.